# Include jQuery files in Node app's DOM on localhost

Tags: jquery, node.js, dom

So I got jQuery to work in my Node app. Let's say I have the following code:

```
var body = '<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body>'+
    '<script type="text/javascript">'+
    '$(document).ready(function(){ alert('hey'); }); '+
    '</script>'+
    '</body>'+
    '</html>';

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.write(body);
response.end();
```

This works fine. However when I want to try and include a JS file like this (in the head):

```
 '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>'
```

I get a 404 error even though the script is in the right place (and the 8888 port is also the correct port)
This is the error I get:

```
  GET http://localhost:8888/scripts/main.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty new to node.

Comment: And do you serve the JS file ? It's not enough for the file to exist : you have to ask node to send it on request.

Comment: Does this mean doing a require('./scripts/main') ?

Comment: No, this means about what Shaun started to explain. Look at the gist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stream the file if your doing it this way, node does not know about it otherwise.

Alternatively use a a templating system that deals with static files

See this gist for streaming the file 
https://gist.github.com/rpflorence/701407

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your answer itself, don't link to it.

Comment: I suggest using express framework (or something similar). It helps you serve static files much easily.

Comment: So I've installed Express and set it up like this:

`var express = require('express');
var app = express(); app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);` 

However, I'm still getting a 404

Comment: (to clarify ive also changed the directory structure and am trying to include it from lib/scripts/main.js (ive also changed the script tag in the html) )